# Remove extra commas, space & lines offset in .csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pdf

I have a **5 pages pdf file**, each page has a table that I need extract. I need to extract all the tables from each page and save them as a data-frame file all using python so i converted the file, to a csv file using **tabula**

```
tabula.convert_into('input.pdf', "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')
```

The main issue with the file **output.csv** is that there are **several extra commas**.

**Example**

```
Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
181,ALEX,,,,20,987
182,Julia,,,,18,8.390
183,Marian,,,,21,9.170
184,Julien,,0,175,60,9.095
Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
215,Asma,26,,35,19,3.807
216,Juan,,,,20,7.982
217,Rami,,,,10,1.832
Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
415,Jessica,,4 920,8 873,538,7.994
416,Karen,,890,6,12,9.993
417,Andrea,,0,69,283,7.200
Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
419,Rym,10,,18,,10,7.196
420,Noor,10,,70,,910,8.291
421,Nathalie,0,,5,,0,0.900
"",Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
456,,Joe,,10,13,0,74.917
457,,Loula,,0,18,11,9.990
458,,Maria,,0,15,172,6.425
459,,Carl,,15,17,11,3.349
Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
566,Diego,,,,0,3.680
567,Carla,0,,26,1,19.361
```

When i convert the csv file into row/columns i got some lines offset

**Check the image below to get the problem:**
[image]
As you can see in the image there are some lines offset(each table in each page of file has specific lines offset) how can i fix this problem

**NB:**
The dataframe should have 6 columns with empty fields.
I guess the extra commas comes from space in the pdf file. how can i remove extra commas from csv file or removing extra space on pdf file.

The expected output in the image below:
[image]

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: From you example, I see that an extra comma ```,``` is present after **Name** and if you remove it, you will have six values as you need. ```182,Julia,,18,79,98,8.390``` -> After removing that comma after ```Julia```, it would be ```182,Julia,18,79,98,8.390``` - This is six values.

Comment: Can you add some more rows to your text example

Comment: Ok i will update my post

Comment: Your expected output has Jessica as 4,920 years old -- I suspect that that is incorrect.

Comment: As you have presented it, your CSV from Tabula is not usable. Also, without your PDF file it is difficult for us to understand why the CSV output is not good. Is Jessica really 4920 years old? And here score of 8873 is way higher than everybody else. Do you get better results if you use Tabula one page at a time? Have you tried **multiple_tables=True** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am basing my strategy on a short regular expression to capture the first 2 columns, and the numbers at the end.

```
(\d+,[^,]+,) → numbers + comma + anything but comma + comma
,*           → zero or more commas
(\d.+)       → the rest of the line starting from the first number
```

Then I am concatenating those two groups inserting enough commas in the middle so that the total is 5 (= 6 columns).

The seems like a pretty straightforward approach to me. It will work for any variation of input where random spaces and commas are inserted as long as the numeric data is right-aligned.

```
import re,io

def fix_line(line):
    # remove duplicate commas and spaces 
    line = re.sub(',,', ',', line.replace(' ', ''))
    # groups: first two rows / middle (non-captured) / numbers
    match = re.match(r'(\d+,[^,]+,),*(\d.+)', line)
    if not match: # removes the headers
        return ''
    # align numbers to right: 6 columns = 5 commas
    return match.groups()[0]+(','*(5-2-match.groups()[1].count(',')))+match.groups()[1]
    

data_corr = [fix_line(line) for line in lines]

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(data_corr)),
                 names=re.sub(',,+', ',', lines[0]).split(',') # assign column names
                )
```

Assuming this input as the variable `lines`:

```
['Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus',
 '181,ALEX,,,,20,987',
 '182,Julia,,,,18,8.390',
 '183,Marian,,,,21,9.170',
 '184,Julien,,0,175,60,9.095',
 'Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus',
 '215,Asma,26,,35,19,3.807',
 '216,Juan,,,,20,7.982',
 '217,Rami,,,,10,1.832',
 'Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus',
 '415,Jessica,,4 920,8 873,538,7.994',
 '416,Karen,,890,6,12,9.993',
 '417,Andrea,,0,69,283,7.200',
 'Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus',
 '419,Rym,10,,18,,10,7.196',
 '420,Noor,10,,70,,910,8.291',
 '421,Nathalie,0,,5,,0,0.900',
 '"",Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus',
 '456,,Joe,,10,13,0,74.917',
 '457,,Loula,,0,18,11,9.990',
 '458,,Maria,,0,15,172,6.425',
 '459,,Carl,,15,17,11,3.349',
 'Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus',
 '566,Diego,,,,0,3.680',
 '567,Carla,0,,26,1,19.361']
```

output:

```
     Id      Name     Age   Score  Rang    Bonus
0   181      ALEX     NaN     NaN    20  987.000
1   182     Julia     NaN     NaN    18    8.390
2   183    Marian     NaN     NaN    21    9.170
3   184    Julien     0.0   175.0    60    9.095
4   215      Asma    26.0    35.0    19    3.807
5   216      Juan     NaN     NaN    20    7.982
6   217      Rami     NaN     NaN    10    1.832
7   415   Jessica  4920.0  8873.0   538    7.994
8   416     Karen   890.0     6.0    12    9.993
9   417    Andrea     0.0    69.0   283    7.200
10  419       Rym    10.0    18.0    10    7.196
11  420      Noor    10.0    70.0   910    8.291
12  421  Nathalie     0.0     5.0     0    0.900
13  456       Joe    10.0    13.0     0   74.917
14  457     Loula     0.0    18.0    11    9.990
15  458     Maria     0.0    15.0   172    6.425
16  459      Carl    15.0    17.0    11    3.349
17  566     Diego     NaN     NaN     0    3.680
18  567     Carla     0.0    26.0     1   19.361
```

NB. if the input is a file then first read lines using:

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this a bit easier to follow than [Martin Evans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68411347/383793)

It's a the generator yields lines of the same length as the cleaned up first line. And removes the first empty string until a line has the right length.

Like Martin's answer it yields your expected dataframe from your example data.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import csv

f = StringIO("""Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
181,ALEX,,,,20,987
182,Julia,,,,18,8.390
183,Marian,,,,21,9.170
184,Julien,,0,175,60,9.095
Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
215,Asma,26,,35,19,3.807
216,Juan,,,,20,7.982
217,Rami,,,,10,1.832
Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
415,Jessica,,4 920,8 873,538,7.994
416,Karen,,890,6,12,9.993
417,Andrea,,0,69,283,7.200
Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
419,Rym,10,,18,,10,7.196
420,Noor,10,,70,,910,8.291
421,Nathalie,0,,5,,0,0.900
"",Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
456,,Joe,,10,13,0,74.917
457,,Loula,,0,18,11,9.990
458,,Maria,,0,15,172,6.425
459,,Carl,,15,17,11,3.349
Id,Name,Age,,Score,Rang,Bonus
566,Diego,,,,0,3.680
567,Carla,0,,26,1,19.361""")


def clean_up(csv_file):
    header = None
    for line in csv_file:
        if not header:
            header = [v for v in line if v]
            length = len(header)
            continue
        while len(line) > length:
            line.remove('')
        if line != header:
            yield(dict(zip(header,line)))

df = pd.DataFrame(clean_up(csv.reader(f)))
print(df)
```

Which gives you:

```
     Id      Name    Age  Score Rang   Bonus
0   181      ALEX                 20     987
1   182     Julia                 18   8.390
2   183    Marian                 21   9.170
3   184    Julien      0    175   60   9.095
4   215      Asma     26     35   19   3.807
5   216      Juan                 20   7.982
6   217      Rami                 10   1.832
7   415   Jessica  4 920  8 873  538   7.994
8   416     Karen    890      6   12   9.993
9   417    Andrea      0     69  283   7.200
10  419       Rym     10     18   10   7.196
11  420      Noor     10     70  910   8.291
12  421  Nathalie      0      5    0   0.900
13  456       Joe     10     13    0  74.917
14  457     Loula      0     18   11   9.990
15  458     Maria      0     15  172   6.425
16  459      Carl     15     17   11   3.349
17  566     Diego                  0   3.680
18  567     Carla      0     26    1  19.361
```

Answer (score 0):

After loading the CSV contents into the `dataframe`, drop the third column and you will have the data in the format you need.

*Note: I haven't added any column names here. You can add them later after dropping the column*

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['181,ALEX,,,,20,987', '182,Julia,,18,79,98,8.390', '183,Marian,,21,89,70,9.170', '184,Julien,,,,60,9.095']

df = pd.DataFrame([sub.split(",") for sub in l])

df.drop(2, inplace=True, axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
Output:

     0       1   3   4   5      6
0  181    ALEX          20    987
1  182   Julia  18  79  98  8.390
2  183  Marian  21  89  70  9.170
3  184  Julien          60  9.095
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach might work, but it is not ideal:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = []

with open('output.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = [v for v in next(csv_input) if v]      # Remove empty column names
    
    for row in csv_input:
        empty = row.index('')
        row = [v.replace(' ', '') for v in row if v]
        
        if row[0] != 'Id':
            row = row[:empty] + ['' for _ in range(6 - len(row))] + row[empty:]
            data.append(row)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
print(df)
```

Giving you:

```
     Id      Name   Age Score Rang   Bonus
0   181      ALEX               20     987
1   182     Julia               18   8.390
2   183    Marian               21   9.170
3   184    Julien     0   175   60   9.095
4   215      Asma    26    35   19   3.807
5   216      Juan               20   7.982
6   217      Rami               10   1.832
7   415   Jessica  4920  8873  538   7.994
8   416     Karen   890     6   12   9.993
9   417    Andrea     0    69  283   7.200
10  419       Rym    10    18   10   7.196
11  420      Noor    10    70  910   8.291
12  421  Nathalie     0     5    0   0.900
13  456       Joe    10    13    0  74.917
14  457     Loula     0    18   11   9.990
15  458     Maria     0    15  172   6.425
16  459      Carl    15    17   11   3.349
17  566     Diego                0   3.680
18  567     Carla     0    26    1  19.361
```

It works by removing all blank entries, and then pads remaining entries after where the first blank entry was back to 6 values. As the age column appears to be optional it might not be 100% reliable.

Comment: I appreciate your time and consideration but this is not working because it delete some data from the next table. The fact that there is some lines offset

Comment: @Prestige, try the updated version, no data is now removed, only blank entries

Comment: I still got offset rows

Comment: There is no obvious solution, I would suggest a better PDF converter. It is not possible to know the difference between a  space or missing data.

Comment: @Prestige You should add those offset rows to your example data. I've written a slightly simpler version which doesn't need to read all data into memory twice. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68439928/383793